# Not able to set generated access_token in request object

Tags: jwt, nestjs

I am authenticating user with the help of JWT token and @nestjs/passport library. I am able to successfully generate and return the access token but stuck at how to set it in the req object. So that I can validate other api routes until user logs out

Below code shows how I generated the access_token and returned to the calling point

```
  let payload = { username: user.email, sub: user.id }
  const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign(payload);

  return {
    expires_in: 3600,
    access_token: accessToken,
    status: 200
  }
```

I am getting the access_token correctly. I verified generated access_token using https://jwt.io/ debugger and results were correct.
Can someone help me in setting up the req object with access_token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple way you could send JWT token in your requests. If you have followed this tutorial: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication, you are using [passport-jwt](https://github.com/mikenicholson/passport-jwt/tree/master/lib) library for JWT. One way is through header if you don't set auth schema it will be this one:

`Authorization: JWT <-HERE YOU SHOULD INSERT TOKEN->`

If you set `authSchema` to be `bearer`, then you could use this header like this:

`Authorization: BEARER <-HERE YOU SHOULD INSERT TOKEN->`

Except for that you can put your JWT into URL like this:

`https://example.com/me?auth_token=<-HERE YOU SHOULD INSERT TOKEN->`

Or in object body that you are sending with property named `auth_token`:

`https://example.com/me`

```
Body:
{
  auth_token: <-HERE YOU SHOULD INSERT TOKEN->
}
```

You can find this in the source code of `passport-jwt` in this [file](https://github.com/mikenicholson/passport-jwt/blob/master/lib/extract_jwt.js).